# Is it possible to import Ozi Explorer waypoints with background and foreground colours to QGIS?

Tags: qgis

OziExplorer allows one to create waypoints with a range of background and foreground colours.  I use this to classify and display waypoint properties by various background and foreground colours.
If I export a Shapefile of the waypoints from OziExplorer, they import fine into QGIS with correct location, but without any colour data.

[image]

Even if the colour data could be imported in the Shapefile, is there any way it could be used to create similarly displayed waypoints in QGIS?

Comment: If you mean creating dashes and dots then yes, you can make very similar looking symbology. The [documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html) for symbology might help.